# Creating own function to convert from string codified number to float in C language

Tags: c, string, floating-point

I'm trying to do a simple function to convert a number codified in a string form to a float, using the function below (attached also), *without* using the function `strtof`.

I'm getting wrong values, could somebody solve this? Why is this giving me incorrect values?

For example if the input string is `"123456789.123"` the function will return a float value of `123456789.123...`

Im using DevC++

```
if string == "12345678"
output = 12345678.000000 (CORRECT)

if string == "-12345678"
output = -12345678.000000 (CORRECT)

if string == "123456789"
output = 123456792.000000 (INCORRECT)

if string == "-123456789"
output = -123456792.000000 (INCORRECT)

if string == "1000.1"
output = 999.799988 (INCORRECT)

if string == "-1000.1"
-output = -999.799988 (INCORRECT)
```

My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


float StringToFloat (uint8_t *var);


int main()
{
    uint8_t string[64] = "-1000.1";

    float value = StringToFloat (string);

    printf("%f", value);

    return 0;
}



float StringToFloat (uint8_t *var)
{
    float multiplier;
    float result = 0;
    bool negative_num = false;
    bool found_comma_or_dot = false;
    uint16_t numbers_before_dot = 0;
    uint16_t numbers_after_dot = 0;
    uint16_t i = 0;

    while (*(var+i) != 0) 
    {
        if (*(var+i) == '-') { negative_num = true; }
        else if (*(var+i) == '.' || *(var+i) == ',') { found_comma_or_dot = true; }
        else 
        {
            if (found_comma_or_dot == false) { numbers_before_dot++; }
            if (found_comma_or_dot == true)  { numbers_after_dot++; }   
        }

        i++;
    }

    multiplier = pow (10, numbers_before_dot-1);


    while (*var != 0) 
    {
        if (*var == '-') { var++; }

        if (numbers_before_dot > 0) 
        {
            numbers_before_dot--;
            result += ( (*var) - 0x30) * (multiplier);
            multiplier /= 10;
        }


        else if (numbers_after_dot > 0) 
        {
            numbers_after_dot--;    
            result += ( (*var) - 0x30) * (multiplier);
            multiplier /= 10;
        }

        var++;
    }

    if (negative_num == true) 
    {
        result *= (-1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is precision. A `float` is simply not very precise. In order to pass your test cases, change from `float` to `double`. This can be seen if you run this code:

```
float t = 123456789;
printf("%f\n", t);
```

Your code is very overly complex. Here is a much more slick solution.

```
double StringToFloat(uint8_t *var)
{
        // First check if negative. If it is, just step one step forward
        // and treat the rest as a positive number. But remember the sign.
        double sign = 1; 
        if(*var=='-') {
                sign = -1;
                var++;
        }

        // Read until either the string terminates or we hit a dot
        uint32_t integer_part = 0;
        while(*var != 0) {
                if(*var == '.' || *var == ',') {
                        var++;
                        break;
                }

                integer_part = 10*integer_part + (*var - '0');
                var++;
        }

        // If we hit the string terminator in previous loop, we will do so
        // in the beginning of this loop too. If you think it makes things
        // clearer, you can add the boolean found_comma_or_dot to explicitly
        // skip this loop.
        uint32_t decimal_part = 0;
        uint32_t decimal_size = 0;
        while(*var != 0) {
                decimal_part = 10*decimal_part + (*var - '0');
                var++;
                decimal_size++;
        }

        return sign * (integer_part + decimal_part/pow(10, decimal_size));
}
```

Note that I changed `uint16_t` to `uint32_t` because I'm using them in another way. If this is not a viable option for you, you can change them to a floating type, but that may cause loss of precision.

There are reasons for using `uint16_t` and `float`, but the you will have to live with the limitations. That's just the way it is.

Comment: I'm using your function now and its working perfectly on DevCpp. But I am using DevCpp only for tests, actualy I'm on a microcontroller (Microchip PIC32MX, MIPS processor). There is a little difference of results between them, check: 
[input = "1000.13", DevC output = 1000.130000, MCU output = 1000.130005] and [input = "1000.12", DevC output = 1000.120000, MCU output = 1000.119995].

Comment: And I'm using all the variables in double type and printing as %lf. Is there any way to correct this difference? The number of digits after the decimal point can be just 2 or 3 at the maximum, that's suitable for me. How can I truncate the number os digits to 2 or 3 after the decimal point in this case? Thanks very much for your reply, I can't vote for your post because I don't have reputation of 15 yet, but probably I will mark your reply as answer.

Comment: Floating numbers are inprecise. That's just the way it is. If you want exact results, then don't use floats. And yes, the result of the same float operation may differ from cpu to cpu. If you want to truncate the decimal part you have to decide if you want to do it when printing or converting. I recommend printing. Then just just study the documentation for printf and it will tell you how to format it. If you want to break the conversion after three decimals, then just introduce a counter in the last loop.

Comment: For example, On the MCU, input = 1000.12 results in 1000.119995, how to round it to 1000.12?

Comment: 1000.12 cannot be exactly represented by a float. That's just the way it is.

Comment: You can try this on your MCU: `double t = 1000.12; printf("%lf\n", t);` to see what you get.

Comment: For my current application, 1 digit after the decimal point is ok. Supposing I want more precision on a next project, I can consider suitable the results that I obtained with the MCU, like 1000.12 input resulting in 11.9995 output, there is a very little error for minus and more. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, inputing 1000.12 directly, the output is also 1000.119995. As you said, there are values that a double can't represent

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that float doesn't have enough precision to represent the number 123456789. We have 123456789 ≥ 2^26; in that range float can only represent multiples of 8.

The error for numbers with decimal point is caused by you treating the decimal point like an additional digit instead of ignoring it. Since the ASCII code for "." is two less than the code for "0", that "." is treated like a digit "-2".

PS. Using 0x30 instead of '0' is very bad style.

PS. Use double instead of float unless you have a very good reason that you can explain clearly why you wouldn't.